# "yum install tcltls" give error "No package tcltls available" on centOS

Tags: centos, tcl, yum

```
[root@localhost /]# yum install tcltls
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Setting up Install Process
No package tcltls available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost /]#
```

and browser does not allow to open this webpage

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/tcltls-1.6.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/tcltls-devel-1.6.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: I can access the pages (as for the browser thingie). Besides: What is the output of `yum -v repolist enabled` (your should be expecting `tcltls` from a registered and enabled repo).

Answer (score 0):

`tcltls` is provided via the `epel` repo:

```
Available Packages
Name        : tcltls
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.6.7
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 35 k
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : OpenSSL extension for Tcl
URL         : http://tls.sourceforge.net/
Licence     : BSD
Description : A TLS OpenSSL extension for Tcl
```

Have a look in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` it may just require `enabled=1` being set. If you don't have the `.repo` file at all then you can fetch it from [here](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm) as an RPM.

Install with `rpm -ivh <name or url>` and remember to set `enabled=1`